# Display and login problem after installing CUDA toolkit 6.5 for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I'm using workstation T5500 with graphic card Quadro k5000.
I installed the graphic driver using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

The computer then could recognize the graphic card. Then I installed the Cuda toolkit v6.5 using

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

After i reboot the computer, i could not login and the screen resolution changed.

Note: i got no problem installing Cuda toolkit v5.5 through

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Hope to get support from you

Best regards